# disable singup button if user not available without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Check user from table users if user available then show signup button other wise it should be disable or color changed.

Comment: Seriously, how do you expect people to respond to that? You must have seen the good practice guidelines before ...Like https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Create a "page" that will return this info with xml or json...in the page make an Ajax call to the page...read the results and show or hide the button.